# Canadian permanent residence under experience class

Tags: canada, resident-permit, express-entry

My IELTS scores are:

```
reading 5.5 
speaking 6.0 
listening 5.5 
writing 4.0
```

I also have 2 years of Canadian experience. My job is at NOC B level. Why was my application rejected?

Comment: What country are you apply to, and what reason was given for the rejection?

Comment: You don't seem to meet the English (or French) language requirements. For NOC B, you need at least CLB 5 which means the Writing score needs to be 5.0. See [this page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp).

Comment: @mkennedy, Do you know what the question is?

Comment: @ouflak I edited the question yesterday but it had to be approved. OP is trying for Canadian permanent residence. At least one reason it was denied is the IELTS scores. It's not a duplicate of our express entry IELTS question.

Answer (score 1):

With a job classification of NOC B and applying under the Canadian Experience class, you have to have English language scores that equal a Canadian Language Board (CLB) of CLB 5 or 6. The equivalent IELTS scores are:

```
IELTS

NOC   CLB Level      Test results for each ability
                    Listening  Reading  Writing  Speaking
B         6            5.5       5.0      5.5      5.5 
B         5            5.0       4.0      5.0      5.0
```

Source: [Language testing](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp)

Because your Writing score is 4.0, you do not appear to meet the English qualification. There may be other reasons why your application was refused, but this is almost certainly one of them.